# Multiple data access object, and a single persistence object

Tags: java

Generally speaking I want to create a single object that hides lower-level access to data: mostly querying and loading, but also saving (read on). Let's call it `ObjectRepository`.

`ObjectRepository`, when created, is given multiple Data Sources objects, implementing `DataSourceInterface`. So at this stage I have one `ObjectRepository` to rule all Data Sources.

Now I want to add a persistence ability to `ObjectRepository`. To simplify things, I want only one of the `DataSource` objects to be also a persisting one (say, it implements extra `DataPersistanceInterface`) - so that I don't have to indicate it every time I save data, i.e. always use this default one.

What is the best approach to the code design, when at the time of creating `ObjectRepository` I want to indicate one of `DataSource` object as the one being also responsible for persistence? Should I use some indexing for each `DataSource` object, and indicate the persisting one by this index? Or is there a better way?

Comment: this is way too confusing, what are you using besides java, hibernate, jpa?  what datasource are you refering to, the one that initialises the connection to a database and contains username and password information? [This datasource?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) Maybe you wish to hear people suggest a generic DAO object?

Comment: ObjectRepository is a custom object at the moment, and no technology chosen yet, as I'm on the very early stage of designing the architecture. Therefore I had to generalize. The actual problem is like this: some data are dynamically created (after processing multiple other sources), while the other are statically persisted in data base. The result however is every time the same: the same Entity object, whether I load it from DB, or create it dynamically. DataSource objects have to be responsbile for hiding how Entity is created.

Comment: Oh, it's not DataSource as in javax.sql, it's more general, I just made it up. Sorry for possible confusion. There will be the only one database between DataSource objects - the one where I want to persits data to. Now I'm thinking about both making totally independent, and inject the same object (as DataSource and as DataPersistance) twice responsible for  oprating on the database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really known what you'r doing, and I have many questions, like if you want to query one sql, how do you know which is the right datasource object?

But if you want to set a default writable datasource, I suggest that you separate the reading interface and writing interface. That is you have a `ReadOnlyDatasource` Object and a `PersistDatasource` Object, and set them separately into the `ObjectRepository` object.

Of course, you can have only one `Datasource` interface, but you can have two setter in your `ObjectRepository` so that you can set your persist datasource and can use it as default.